# Shell Script to fix minimum password age not working but no errors

Tags: shell-script, sed, login, password

The goal of this script is to change the minimum password age in the /etc/login.defs file.

My issue is that this script runs, I don't get any errors but when I vi to the file, nothing has changed. I'm not great with sed so I assume something there is wrong. Need assistance figuring out what is wrong with this.

```
min_pass_age=7

sed -i "s/^PASS_MIN_DAYS.*/PASS_MIN_DAYS ${min_pass_age}/" /etc/login.defs
```

Comment: What is the output of `grep "^PASS_MIN_DAYS.*" /etc/login.defs`

Comment: Let me run it and get that for you.

Comment: No worries, figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a few things. Need the /g at the end because it needs to pick up the ones at the beginning of the line and ignore the commented lines. Need to not use double quotes, should only use single.

```
sed -i 's/^PASS_MAX_DAYS.*/PASS_MAX_DAYS 90/g' /etc/login.defs

sed -i 's/^PASS_MIN_DAYS.*/PASS_MIN_DAYS 7/g' /etc/login.defs
```